# What are the options in SharePoint online if we want to extract the logs related to Lists & Libraries and send them to a group of people

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, administration, auditing, audit-log-reports

We have SharePoint online site collection which contain 1 custom list and 1 document library. Now we need to extract the audit logs related to these list and library and send it to a group of people.

So can anyone advice on the available approaches we can follow in SharePoint online?

Previously in SharePoint on-premises, we use to configure the audit logs for a site collection as mentioned in this link [Configure audit settings for a site collection](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-f5a346d0-ee0f-4412-a5e6-d9b5abaa1012). But this approach is no more available for us in SharePoint online.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the audit log reports from a site collection settings.

To view an audit log report:

1. Click **Settings**, then click **Site settings**.
2. Click **Audit log reports** in the **Site Collection Administration** section.
3. Select the report that you want, such as **Deletion** on the View Auditing Reports page, .
4. Type a URL or **Browse** to the library where you want to save the report and then click **OK**.
5. On the Operation Completed Successfully page, click **click here to view this report**.

**Documentation**: [View audit log reports](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527)

---

**Update**:

If you are not able to use above steps, you can get the audit logs in the compliance center.

Check below documentation for more information: [Search the audit log in the compliance center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance)

Comment: but those steps are not available for sharepoint online.. even this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/configure-audit-data-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2 mentioned that it only supported in `SharePoint Server 2019 SharePoint Server 2016 SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise
`

Comment: Check **View audit log reports** link --> which is supported for **SharePoint in Microsoft 365**. And link to **Configure audit settings for a site collection** is given in same documentation.

Comment: If you are not able to use above steps, you can get the audit logs in the compliance center. Check update answer.

Comment: i know about the compliance center logs, but my question is how i can extract info from these logs and send a report of the related logs to a group of people.

Comment: You can use "Audit log search" --> "Filter results" based on activities -->  "Export results". Here is [list of activities audited related to SharePoint lists](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance?#sharepoint-list-activities)

Comment: but can this be automated? to send a report each day for example?

Comment: You can create alerts using **New alert policy** (you can find it under "Audit log search" page). Also, check documentation at [Alert policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/alert-policies).

Comment: alerts works differently , they do not send a report, they send instance emails when the alert is triggered !!!